# Suppressing warnings in pweave

Tags: python, pweave

I have a warning in my LaTeX generated file, something like this:

```
/home/jmerelo/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py:1367: RuntimeWarning: Warning: using box
for unknown shape cylinder
warnings.warn(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding),
RuntimeWarning)
```

Due to an old version of graphviz, but that's not really relevant. I have been trying to suppress warnings in pweave, but there does not seem to be a way to supress warnings by chunk; `PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"` does not seem to affect it either; finally, there does not seem to be a way of getting pweave to pass options like -W through to Python. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"` in front of the command you are going to use to eventually invoke `pweave`, or `export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"` anywhere before that in the same console.